# Combine __in and contains query filter to make a more complex filter in django

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

So here's my question :
Say i have a list of some people's full names and I want to filter my users to check which one of those people are already of my users.

The problem is that users have first name and last name but what I have is the list  of full names, meaning 'first_name+last_name'.

I was trying to filter in 3 steps, first filter all users whose first_names where in the list and then filter with their last_name.The third step would be to check for exact matches between the results, But the problem is I can't filter my users with their first_name in the list because `__in` operator looks for exact matches not partial matches.
**So**:
Is there anyway to do a filter like this :

```
users.filter(first_name__in__icontains=list_of_people)
```

or even better, can i have a filter like :

```
users.filter((first_name+ ' ' + last_name)__in=list_of_people)
```

?
Any help would be appreciated :)
 Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem possible with normal queryset to me, I guess you need to iterate through the list and find the matches, something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q     

qs = User.objects.all()
for fullname in list_of_names:
    firstname, lastname = fullname.split()
    qs = qs.filter(
        Q(first_name__icontains = firstname), 
        Q(last_name__icontains = lastname)
    )
```

Another option would be using [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) which can be okay for this case, the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) IN (list_of_name)
```

But this is not case insensitive and you should try to avoid raw query anyway.

Comment: Well This can't be used because it's not like fullname.split() will give first name and last name, consider an arabic name, seyed mohammad ali blah blah ... , we don't know what's the first name and what's the last name ... :)

Comment: Well this is just a basic example, if you can't construct the SQL in your head then you can't make the queryset correctly ;)